# Does Shohobohaum Za character allude to the USSR?

Tags: inspiration, the-culture, language-explanation, player-of-games

The ambassador Shohobohaum Za in The Player of Games by Iain M. Banks shows the following features.

- He is a drunkard and has propensity to brawls – a known stereotype of a Russian.
- He dismantles a device (video camera) using some crude tools – yet another trait associated with the Soviet Union.
- He once says a pseudo-Russian word *Cultur[nik](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA#Suffix)* (referring to citizens of The Culture).

If this is an allusion, then can we infer that The Culture portrays a sort of the West and the Soviets (as of 1987) lumped together?

Comment: This seems... unlikely in the extreme. The Culture is the ideal socialist utopia, hardly something that plays the part of "the West" in comparison to the USSR. And how is "dismantling a device using tools" a trait associated with the Soviets?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: not just “dismantling using tools”, but (successfully) using makeshift tools on some complex device. A strong do-it-yourself and fix-it-yourself spirit existed in the USSR and it was not confined to engineers and hard-boiled technology fans. Of course such abilities are not uncommon in the USA (and elsewhere in the West), but such people mostly are making career in technology, not government service.

Comment: Daniel Roseman's ideological analysis is a bit facile: It is possible that the entire _Empire of Azad_ was given traits corresponding to popular images of the USSR or Russians. Authors are constantly looking for traits to give their characters, and pop culture stereotypes (or even real life traits) of existing people are good hunting grounds. That said, there's no guarantee that there is any allegory or allusion intended.  Without something stronger, ideally Word of Banks, there's no way to know.

Comment: Given Banks' ideological views it is just as likely that Za is modeled on a CIA or MI6 station chief. He has the characteristic alcoholism and desire for excitement of a pastured Western spy, but like the successful ones, plays on such perceptions to be effective in his covert role.

Comment: "a pseudo-Russian word Culturnik" — https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/культурник

Comment: @user28434: OK, it’s an *obscure* dictionary word. Note that Russian is my native language.